# How do I create a raw HTML form with buttons to store data directly to google docs

Tags: html, wordpress, web-deployment, google-docs

The form should have an input field and a Submit button on a single line to capture users Emails and I'm doing with all styling inside an html code only no css.

Guys please I need help on this as I've been struggling with this for days without any success. I have checked previous solutions still couldn't find a way around it.

Any work around on this will be gladly appreciated

```
<a class="btn btn-buy btn-lg wt_scroll" href="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1zFx4183jB_T7CDGJ_WK3nwRcXmqnIVzvyWfkZJwzgoU/viewform" style="height: 60px; margin-left:-20px; font-size: 25px"> <span class="">Problem Here</span></a>

<a input type="email" name="EMAIL" required="" placeholder="Enter Your Email" style="width: 50%; height: 34px; display: block; color: #03c9a9; font-size: 20px; font-weight:400; font-family: Raleway, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; border: 2px solid #03c9a9;"></a>

<a input type="submit" value="Sign Up" style="width: 40%; height: 34px; display: block; color: #fff; font-size: 20px; font-weight:400; text-transform:none; font-family: Raleway, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; border: 2px solid #cfcfcf;">
```

I was able to get the submit problem here but I couldn't figure the one to capture user email to google

Comment: This is not freelancer site to code for you. post your problem along with a issue so that we can assist

Comment: <input type="email" name="EMAIL" required="" placeholder="Enter Your Email" style="width: 50%; height: 34px; display: block; color: #03c9a9; font-size: 20px; font-weight:400; font-family: Raleway, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; border: 2px solid #03c9a9;"><input type="submit" value="Sign Up" style="width: 40%; height: 34px; display: block; color: #fff; font-size: 20px; font-weight:400; text-transform:none; font-family: Raleway, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; border: 2px solid #cfcfcf;">

Comment: @Soorapadman Sorry about that, I just edited my post and included the html code.

Comment: @Soorapadman thanks, how do I now get it to store a captured email to google docs?

Answer (score 0):

The way you create the text field is wrong it should be like this

```
<input type="submit" value="Sign Up">
Not 
<a input type="submit" value="Sign Up" >
```